# Run at startup and monitor redis and node.js processes

Tags: node.js, deployment, redis, upstart, monit

I want to deploy node.js app which depends on redis. Both processes will run on the same VPS. There are plenty of examples on [how to daemonize and monitor node](http://howtonode.org/deploying-node-upstart-monit) and I've also found some [uncommented configuration for redis](https://gist.github.com/cyx/3690597). How do I put it together? Can I just combine these two snippets in one `monitrc` file?

Answer (score 0):

You could use Supervisord to orchestrate the launch of Redis and your [**NodeJS apps**](http://blog.fgribreau.com/2012/03/process-management-at-bringr.html) (use the `priority` **[parameter](http://supervisord.org/configuration.html#program-x-section-settings)** to start Redis before your apps). Supervisord will automatically restart your NodeJS app if they crash.

You can then setup monit over it to be alerted when something wrong happens and to restart your NodeJS processes if they use too much memory/cpu or if they are not accessible anymore from a specific port.